# Error on basic Java program - cannot find symbol ActionListener()

Tags: java

I have pieced together the following `HelloWorld` type of program that opens a window, displays a button and then handles the button click by closing the window.  I am getting an error when compiling on the part where I am adding the `ActionListener` to handle the click event. Looking at other samples and tutorials around the net, this looks like it should work. Any ideas?

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyTest{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
    guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    guiFrame.setTitle("Example GUI"); 
    guiFrame.setSize(300,250);  
    guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  

      JButton btn = new JButton("Hit Me");

      btn.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
      guiFrame.close();
      }
     });
      guiFrame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      guiFrame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Error:

```
javac MyTest.java
MyTest.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
          btn.addActionListener( new actionListener(){
                                     ^
  symbol:   class actionListener
  location: class MyTest
1 error
```

Comment: Try to import import java.awt.event.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674797/error-when-compiling-java-program-cannot-find-symbol

Comment: as far as I'm concerned you need to first fix the issue that is coming from `guiFrame.close();` the compiler complains about this before anything else. `Cannot refer to a non-final variable guiFrame inside an inner class defined in a different method`

Comment: error message `btn.addActionListener( new actionListener(){` --> should be `ActionListener`. Seems like your code does not not match the error message?

Comment: I don't know why nobody is pointing that `guiFrame.close()` is one of the reason that the code in not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is working, Here is what I did :

1. add `import java.awt.event.*;`
2. remove unnecessary `import java.util.*;`
3. **replaced `guiFrame.close()` with `guiFrame.dispose();`** as There is no `Frame.close()` method.

Here is the working code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("Example GUI");
        guiFrame.setSize(300, 250);
        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Hit Me");

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                guiFrame.dispose();
            }
        });
        guiFrame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: That did it, but why? Shouldn't the first line already include that?

Comment: No, the wildcard referes to classes, not subpackages (which actually don't exist). If not, then a `import java.*` will be enough for most the java programs

Comment: With `import` we imports `classes`, `enums`, `interfaces` etc. not packages or elements inside packages. @JohnS And there is also 1 more error that you are using `close()` method which doesn't exists.

Answer (score 2):

`ActionListener` is in the `java.awt.event` package. If you import that package, it should work.

The `import java.awt.*;` statement does not import the `java.awt.event` package, in which the `ActionListener` class resides. To import, you will need to separately `import java.awt.event.*;'

Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) for more details, under 'Apparent Hierarchies of Packages'.

Comment: Doesn't java.awt.* import all of the libraries under the java.awt namespace?

Comment: @JohnS No : "Importing java.awt.* imports all of the types in the java.awt package, but it does not import java.awt.color, java.awt.font, or any other java.awt.xxxx packages. If you plan to use the classes and other types in java.awt.color as well as those in java.awt, you must import both packages with all their files"

Comment: @Mohammad, he imported the java.awt package, not the java.awt.event package.

Comment: `java.awt.*` does contain `java.awt.event`

Comment: @Mohammad, no it doesn't. From the link I have attached; Importing java.awt.* imports all of the types in the java.awt package, but it does not import java.awt.color, java.awt.font, or any other java.awt.xxxx packages. If you plan to use the classes and other types in java.awt.color as well as those in java.awt, you must import both packages with all their files:

Comment: @PeterK For the sake of making sure, I tried it in Eclipse and by doing `import java.awt.*;` I can use `Font f;` with absolutely no problem.

Comment: @Mohammad, `Font` is in the `java.awt` package, which is different from the `java.awt.font` package. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/package-summary.html vs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no hierarchy of packages.

`java.awt.event` is not a sub-package of `java.awt`. Therefore `import java.awt.*` doesn't import the classes of `java.awt.event`.

> At first, packages appear to be hierarchical, but they are not. For
>   example, the Java API includes a java.awt package, a java.awt.color
>   package, a java.awt.font package, and many others that begin with
>   java.awt. However, the java.awt.color package, the java.awt.font
>   package, and other java.awt.xxxx packages are not included in the
>   java.awt package. The prefix java.awt (the Java Abstract Window
>   Toolkit) is used for a number of related packages to make the
>   relationship evident, but not to show inclusion.
>
> Importing java.awt.* imports all of the types in the java.awt package,
>   but it does not import java.awt.color, java.awt.font, or any other
>   java.awt.xxxx packages. If you plan to use the classes and other types
>   in java.awt.color as well as those in java.awt, you must import both
>   packages with all their files:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.color.*;`
```

([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html))